# Changing a material effects both text objects

Tags: materials, linked-data, text-object

I am making a Banner for a friend, I have it mirrored and pretty, Same text twice, The main one with bevels and Glass. The one behind it as an Emission source for light to get a nice reflection.

Now here is the problem, I was wondering why it wasn't detailed, When I move back and fourth between the two Text items, They keep moving the properties! Example, I change the color of the Emission text, Suddenly the Glass text isn't glass but it also has Emission property now, For some reason when I change anything on one, It changes in the other.

Comment: do they have separate materials ?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this is because both text objects are assigned the same material (this could happen if you duplicated one from the other).  If a material (or any other datablock, i.e. particle system, image, etc.) has multiple users it will display the number of users in a small box to the right of the material name.  To make a single user copy of the material simply click on that box.

[image]
The material `"Material"` has 2 users, clicking on the <kbd>2</kbd> box will create a new material with all the same properties and name it `"Material.000"`.  Changing this new material will not affect the original material `"Material"`.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that duplicated objects made a duplicate of the material as well. Hmm... if that isn't so, it certainly makes things easier.